# Equivalence classes of triplets satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

The affirmative answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335272/congruence-mod-p) illustrates that the equation

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=0$$

has $p^2-1$ nontrivial solutions over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (solutions that are not $(0,0,0)$).  If $(x,y,z)$ is a nontrivial solution, then so is $(ax,ay,az)$ for $a=1,\ldots,p-1$.  This allows us to define an equivalence relation on the set of nontrivial solutions by $(x,y,z)\sim(x',y',z')$ if and only if $(ax,ay,az)=(x',y',z')$ for some nonzero $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$.  Notice that a counting argument shows that there $p+1$ equivalence classes.  I'd like to be able to write down a set of $p+1$ representatives, one for each class.

For example, if $p=3$, we find that the $3+1=4$ solutions $(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, and $(1,2,2)$ each represent a different equivalence class.

What would the answer be for general $p$?  Most likely the representatives could be indexed by the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ or the group $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ with one or two special representatives.

Comment: This is easy, if $p\equiv1\pmod4$, for then $-1$ has a square root, call it $i$, in $\mathbb{F}_p$. In that case
$$x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy),$$ and we can take $x'=x+iy$ and $y'=x-iy$ as the new variables (inverting the linear transformation is trivial) in the equation
$$x'y'+z^2=0,$$ which is hopefully easier to handle (set $z=1$ or $z=0$ within an equivalence class). Note that a linear transformation preserves the equivalence classes.

Comment: This gives the parametrization of a family of $p-1$ points:
$$(x:y:z)=(\frac{x'-x'^{-1}}2:\frac{x'+x'^{-1}}{2i}:1)$$ with the parameter $x'$ ranging over $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ together with the two extra points
$$(1:i:0),\qquad (1:-i:0).$$ Can't crack the $p\equiv3\pmod4$ case now. Time to hit the sack.